# magic with 4 tools in positions switching

Tags: mathematics, magic

There are 4 tools, on a table, in a row:

> spoon,tablespoon,fork,knife

in positions:

> 4,3,2,1 respectively.

The magician look at their initial arrangement and then turns around. Then a volunteer from the crowd comes by and starts switching between pairs of tools over and over again.

First he makes 10 switches and declares the positions of the tools he switched then he makes one "silent" switch (without saying anything). He then makes 10 more "loud" switches.

After this process the magician turns to the table, looks at the row of tools and picks up one of the tools that the volunteer switched in the "silent" switch. The magician performs the magic by only remembering one number in the range of 1 to 10 that can be changed again and again.

How does he perform the magic?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the point of the question: If the magician can remember a couple of permutations (equivalent to remembering two numbers in the range 1..24), he can just remember what the first 10 "loud" switches did and what the last 10 "loud" switches did, in which case he knows exactly what the configurations immediately before and after the "silent" switch were. So the question is: *if his memory is much worse than that*, only sufficient to hold a single number in the range 1..10, how can he still keep track of enough information to identify one affected tool? Is that right?

Comment: Yes because if he can remember teo larger numbers it is much easier

Comment: Does that number have to be an integer? (otherwise, it's much easier, yet again)

Comment: yes it must be an integer, all this things you suggest will make the question very easy by enabling the magician to remember the layout at each time. @QuestionAsker

Comment: So he makes ten switches, and then lists where all four things are?

Or a "Loud" switch is "I swap fork and knife"?

Comment: He makes ten switches with saying the positions of the two elements he switch (not the elements themselves) and then he makes one switch without saying anything and then again 10 more switches like the first 10 @LeppyR64

Comment: So a  "Loud" switch is "I swap positions one and three".

Comment: Yes indeed @LeppyR64

Comment: @Lior I don't know if I'm right, but I think there are 12 possible permutations at the end of "magic". Is there really a way he could get more information?

Comment: I think I've solved this, the key thing here is the fact that you have to keep track of two of the tools and encode it to your one integer from 1 to 10 that is constantly changing and then you can ignore the silent switch and see if the ending permutation fits your calculation in terms of the two tools you kept track of, if not this means that your two tools were touched but else you know that the other tools were switched i may upload the full answer tomorrow. @Lasoloz

Comment: @Lasoloz: There are only 6 possible silent switches, not even 12, and since we don't need to pinpoint the exact pair, the amount of information needed at the end is even less than log(6) bits. Of course, whether there is an algorithm to do it using only log(6) bits is another matter altogether!

Comment: @user21820, you are right. I did not think about that. I just calculated which permutations can be at step (2k) and which can be at step (2k+1).

Comment: @Lior: Your method does not work because you need 12 possibilities to keep track of the **individual** positions of the two items. If you only keep track of the pair of positions, then you cannot tell whether the swap involved those two or the other two.

Comment: @user21820 Wow yes you are right there is a problem in my method if for example the silent switch involved the two elements i kept track of, i.e. the volunteer swaps between the two elements i keep track of and I can't know that he did at the end.

Comment: @Lasoloz: Anyway I now think it's impossible because I think we need a normal subgroup of $S_4$ and the only such one doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The final permutation done by the volunteer is `σ`

```
α = σ₁₀ σ₉ σ₈ σ₇ σ₆ σ₅ σ₄ σ₃ σ₂ σ₁
β = σ₂₀ σ₁₉ σ₁₈ σ₁₇ σ₁₆ σ₁₅ σ₁₄ σ₁₃ σ₁₂ σ₁₁
σ = β σₛ α
```

where `σᵢ` are transpositions and `σₛ` is the silent transposition.

Then, the magician can

> choose two different numbers `a` and `b` in `{1,2,3,4}`.

Each time the volunteer makes a "loud" transposition, the magician

> does it too on his numbers.

Finally, he gets

> `β α (a)` and `β α (b)`

Then, he checks

> whether the objects which were initially in positions `a` and `b` are now in positions `β α (a)` and `β α (b)`.
>
> - If both are, that means the silent transposition didn't affect these objects. Since there are only 4 objects, the transposition affected the other two.
> - If (at least) one isn't, that means it was affected by the silent transposition.

In order to achieve this, the magician must keep track of two different numbers between `1` and `4`. That's 12 possibilities, which is too much for his limited memory.

However, there is a trick (I'm not sure if this is cheating, but otherwise I think it's impossible):

> he does not need to use his memory in order to keep track of a number.
>  For example, he can store the numbers in his own eyes and tongue, using a code like `1 = up`, `2 = right`, `3 = down`, `4 = left`.

When the volunteer says a loud transposition, the magician does this

> 1. He retrieves the number stored in his eyes and places it in his memory
> 2. He transforms that number according to the transposition
> 3. He stores the new number in his eyes
> 4. He retrieves the number stored in his tongue and places it in his memory
> 5. He transforms that number according to the transposition
> 6. He stores the new number in his tongue
>
> Only one number between 1 and 4 is stored in the memory at a time.
>  
>  Of course, this assumes the transposition and the conversion code do not waste memory. Otherwise, he could use his fingers to store more data.

This will work because the magician is turned around, otherwise the public would realize there is something wrong with his face:

[image]